# Delete or hide the row in set text in mysql result

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to not show the text **row in set (0.10 sec)** in the result of a mysql query

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answered in a comment by [danblack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack):

```
mysql -B --skip-column-names -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%verbosity%'"
```